# Random Guessing Game

Tags: python

I'm learning how to program (specifically using Python) and I can't figure out how to get my code to "play again". If you could help, that'd be great.

```
#This program is a Random Number Guessing game
import random

rand_num = random.randint(1, 100)
count = 1
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100."))

while guess != rand_num:
    count = count + 1
    if guess < rand_num:
        print ('Too low, try again.')
        guess = int(input("What number is it?"))
    elif guess > rand_num:
        print ('Too high, try again.')
        guess = int(input("What number is it?"))


if count > 1:
    print('You Won! It took you', count, 'times.')
else:
    print('You won! It took you', count, 'try.')
```

Comment: Use Infinite loop with Condition that ask user to Play more ..Y or N in if else

Comment: Could you type the code out so I can get a visual please? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Add a while loop around your code.

```
#This program is a Random Number Guessing game
import random

play = True
while play:

    rand_num = random.randint(1, 10)
    count = 1
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10."))

    while guess != rand_num:
        count = count + 1
        if guess < rand_num:
            print ('Too low, try again.')
            guess = int(input("What number is it?"))
        elif guess > rand_num:
            print ('Too high, try again.')
            guess = int(input("What number is it?"))


    if count > 1:
        print('You Won! It took you', count, 'times.')
    else:
        print('You won! It took you', count, 'try.')

    s = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    play = s.lower() in ('y', 'yes', 'ok', 'sure')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import random  
while True:
    rand_num = random.randint(1, 100)
    count = 1
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100."))
    while guess != rand_num:
        count = count + 1
        if guess < rand_num:
            print ('Too low, try again.')
            guess = int(input("What number is it?"))
        elif guess > rand_num:
            print ('Too high, try again.')
            guess = int(input("What number is it?"))


    if count > 1:
        print('You Won! It took you', count, 'times.')
    else:
        print('You won! It took you', count, 'try.')
    print("You want to play more !!! Y or anything else")
    decision = str(input())
    if(decision=="Y"):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring it out, but this was helpful. :D